# How to add a user to approvers list

Tags: servicenow

I'm looking to add a user to the approvers list so they can approve/reject prob record requests. I've done this before but its been a while!

How can this be done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you give a user the `approval_user` or `approval_admin` role, they will be able to approve problem records.